# Ruby. Releasy. Making exe file

Tags: ruby, compilation, exe

I want to share my ruby app with my friends, so I decided to make .exe file, because I don't want them to install Ruby and run my code manually. I try to use releasy with rake file from their example on GitHub. And when I run rake build:windows:wrapper I see this trace:

```
$ rake build:windows:wrapper --trace
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- releasy
/home/edward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/home/edward/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p645/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/home/edward/RubyProjects/SG/Rakefile:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.4.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645@rails_4_0/gems/rake-10.4.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645@rails_4_0/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645@rails_4_0/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
/home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645@rails_4_0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/edward/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p645@rails_4_0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

What should I do? Maybe I should use another gem for this purpose? Ocra didn't work for me, because of a lot of strange errors. Ubuntu 14.04. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `releasy` is not installed, or not in your path.

You should read the error message, and do what it suggests, in this case, install releasy or make it available in your path.

Since you are using rvm, you can install the gem by doing `gem install releasy` without the use of sudo.  If you used sudo, then that explains why it is not in your path, as you are not using the system Ruby.